# Packager won't start after React Native Update

Tags: react-native

I updated my React-Native from 0.15.0 to 0.18.1 and it's giving the following error now. (When trying with `react-native start`)

```
Error building DependencyGraph:
 Error: Naming collision detected: /Users/mymac/research/react-native/rotater/ios-templates/node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js collides with /Users/mymac/research/react-native/rotater/ios-templates/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js
    at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (HasteMap.js:132:13)
    at HasteMap.js:103:28
    at tryCallOne (/Users/mymac/research/react-native/rotater/ios-templates/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/mymac/research/react-native/rotater/ios-templates/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:103:15
    at flush (/Users/mymac/research/react-native/rotater/ios-templates/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:428:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:357:13)
```

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. `npm i`
3. `npm i fbjs`
4. `find . -name 'fbjs' -print`
5. **delete all but the top-level fbjs**
6. `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*`
7. `watchman watch-del-all`
8. `npm cache clean`

I had the same issue after upgrading to version .18.1, this fixed if for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder then reinstalling using `npm install`?

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of an answer